# Spring Data JPA Specification search for property in nested collection

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, criteria

Say I have at least two entities.

```
@Entity
public class Process {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;

    @ManyToAny(
            metaColumn = @Column(name = "node_type"),
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY
    )
    @AnyMetaDef(
            idType = "long", metaType = "string",
            metaValues = {
                    @MetaValue(targetEntity = Milestone.class, value = MILESTONE_DISC),
                    @MetaValue(targetEntity = Phase.class, value = PHASE_DISC)
            }
    )
    @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(
            name = "process_nodes",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "process_id", nullable = false),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "node_id", nullable = false)
    )
    private Collection<ProcessNode> nodes = new ArrayList<>();

    ...
}
```

---

```
@Entity
@ToString
@DiscriminatorValue(MILESTONE_DISC)
public class Milestone implements ProcessNode {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Collection<ResultDefinition> results;

    @ToString.Exclude
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Transient
    private Process process;

...
}
```

Now I want to use spring data jpa specification to find (all) processes which have a milestone with name "S5".

Note that Milestone is a ProcessNode and there is another Entity called Phase which is also a ProcessNode. These can be contained in the "nodes" collection of my Process Entity.

[image: db structure]

I tried to write something like this:

```
    public static Specification<Process> hasMilestoneWithName(final String milestoneName) {
    return (Specification<Process>) (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
        Path<?> namePath = root.join("nodes").get("name");
        return criteriaBuilder.equal(namePath, milestoneName);
    };
}
```

This does not work, but throws:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [nodes] on this ManagedType [com.smatrics.dffs.processservice.model.entities.Process]

I don't really know how to use the API. Examples often refer to a meta-model that would be generated by the IDE or maven, but I really do not want to have any static generated resources. Please help me resolve this with Specification of spring-data-jpa without a generated meta-model.

Also if you could help me write the hql it would be awesome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a simpler alternative, coming from bottom-up:

- Load `Milestone` entities with `name=S5`: `findByName("S5")`
- Return the `Process` for each `Milestone`
- Filter out the duplicates

Or you could even save a few SQL queries by returning not the `Milestone` entity but only the ID of the `Process` for each `Milestone` and then load the `Process` nodes by a list of IDs:

The (native) SQL equivalent would be

```
select *
from process
where id in (
  select process_id
  from milestone
  where name = 'S5'
)
```

Regardless of my solution your `join` does not look completely correct to me but I can't point out what's wrong - maybe there are other methods on the JPA metamodel that return a `CollectionJoin`? Not sure. Probably it is because `@ManyToAny` is not JPA standard so the JPA criteria API does not recognize `nodes` as a valid "joinable" field.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't want to create a repository/service for milestones, since it is only part of the bigger aggregate (process). The native query won't work either  in my opinion, since process_id is not stored in milestone (it is transient and should also be, since the mapping is in the table process_nodes).  

You might be right about @ManyToAny not being standard JPA, but as far as I am aware there is not better way to map the relationship since in JPA there is no feature that supports polymorphism (?)